# How do I NSLog a string from an NSDictionary object?

Tags: objective-c, nslog

Working with Json, how can I "**NSlog**" only the title in this code:

```
NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    // Set text on textLabel
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
    // Set text on detailTextLabel
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"description"]];
```

Something like `NSlog(@"%@", title);` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood what you are asking correctly, then this should do it:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [item objectForKey:@"title"]);
```

If that gives you a compiler warning because the object may not be an NSString, then you can do:

```
NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"%@", title);
```

If I've misunderstood your question, please let me know and I will correct my answer accordingly.